# how would i add a while loop and counter to this code which an admin can use to login

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, counter

```
def login():
    logindetails = {'username':'Admin123' , 'password':'Pass123'}

    username = input("please enter the username")
    password = input("please enter the password")

    if username == 'Admin123':
        print ("username correct")
    else:
        print ("username incorrect")
    if password == 'Pass123':
        print ("password correct")
    else:
        print ("password incorrect")

login()
```

Please tell me where I would put the while loop and how would I format the code to add a counter too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def login():
    logindetails = {'username':'Admin123' , 'password':'Pass123'}

    username = input("please enter the username")
    password = input("please enter the password")
    valid = False
    while valid == False:
        if username == 'Admin123' and password == 'Pass123':
            print ("username and password correct")
            valid = True
            pass
        else:
            print ("username or password incorrect")
        username = input("please enter the username")
        password = input("please enter the password")
```

valid is a bool so the loop wont stop until the username and password is correct.

Or you can have a fail safe where if the user enters the username and password wrong more than say 4 times, it kicks them out.

```
def login():
    logindetails = {'username':'Admin123' , 'password':'Pass123'}

    username = input("please enter the username")
    password = input("please enter the password")
    valid = False
    count = 0
    while count != 4 or valid == False:
        if username == 'Admin123' and password == 'Pass123':
            print ("username and password correct")
            valid == True
            pass
        else:
            print ("username or password incorrect")
            count += 1
        username = input("please enter the username")
        password = input("please enter the password")
    if valid == False:
        print ("Sorry you had too many attempts to login. Try again later")
```

Comment: You should prefer `not valid` over `valid == False`.

Comment: thank you for this could you please answer my other question about pulling data from a file it would be much appreciated

Comment: also after the print or between the if statement is it possible to end the program if the user has had more than four attempts assuming you would use break

Comment: @ThePythonAmateur If this was the answer to your question please select it as the anwser. I'll take a look at your other question!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should initialize username and password variables to empty strings as well as your counter.

Then, you should declare your while loop with for condition, the comparison between

- username and logindetails['username']
- password and logindetails['password'].

If both are the same, you're getting outside the loop, if not, you have to ask again for user inputs and increment the counter.

In other words :

```
username = ""
password = ""
counter = 0

WHILE username != logindetails['username'] AND password != logindetails['password']:
    ASK for user inputs / DISPLAY error messages
    INCREMENT counter

DISPLAY "logged after counter attempts"
```

Does it answer your questions ?

Comment: thank you for this if you could please can you answer my other question about pulling data from a file it would be much appreciated